# How is Android contact information stored?

Tags: android

I'm writing a class that handles Android contact information and after some struggle, I've written a function that retrieves all information about the user's contacts, including all phone numbers, email addresses, postal addresses, etc. However, I still don't understand how this information is stored in the phone, so I'm hoping someone can give me some insight on this.

So, a user can have multiple phone numbers, multiple email addresses, etc. For contacts you have `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI` for the table containing all contacts and for phone numbers you have `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI`. But then there is also `ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI`, which is supposed to contain all the data for your contacts, I think. My assumption is that in the Contacts table, contact ID is the unique identifier for separate rows, whereas for the Phone table, phone number is the unique row identifier. If RawContacts contains all columns of the ContactsContract classes, then there would be no unique identifier for each row, since each contact might be assigned multiple phone numbers, multiple email addresses, etc. In other words, I don't understand how such a table is structured.

So my question is this: Are the various tables containing contact information--Contacts, Phone, Email, StructuredPostal, etc.--completely separate or is the information for each of those tables extracted from the larger RawContacts table? Or am I misunderstand what RawContacts is? Since the class I am writing will help move contacts from the phone contact list into a separate database, knowing this information will help me understand whether I should store the information in multiple databases or just one (similar to how I described the RawContacts database above).

Comment: if your phone is rooted, you can pull the db yourself via ddms and inspect it, it's in `/data/data/com.android.providers.contacts`, you can use [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) Firefox plugin.

Answer (score 1):

The android API Guide on [`Contacts Provider`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html) gives a nice description of how the Contacts tables are stored (it's a bit convoluted, allowing the merge of many contacts)

#### picture of data hierarchy

[image: contacts provider data hierarchy from android api guide]

#### your Q:

> So my question is this: Are the various tables containing contact
>   information--Contacts, Phone, Email, StructuredPostal,
>   etc.--completely separate or is the information for each of those
>   tables extracted from the larger RawContacts table?

Looking over the docs again (I've not coded against these tables, only read docs), the Phone, Email... tables appear to be separate.  However, the information looks to be stored in both tables, the contact and also in the RawContacts.